# Find All a values in ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find the list of inner text values of `span` in `a` elements within one `ul` in a `div`

In other words, having the markup:

```
<div id="MyId">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Val1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Val2</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the array [Val1, Val2] where the div id is my input. I've written some dirty jQuery code involving the `each` on `ul` function but it's more complicated than what it should be.

Comment: $(''#MyId > ul > li > a > span').map(function() { return this.html(); }).get();

Comment: `var arr = $('#MyId ul li a span').map(function() {return this.innerHTML}).get()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myArr = [];

$("#MyId span").each(function() {
    myArr.push($(this).html());
});
```

This would push in your array the values you want.

```
//arr = ["Val1", "Val2"]
```

Having in mind that `.html()` would actually take everything html-wise inside your span. If you just want the text, then use `.text()` instead.

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/vdu93x8e/

Answer (score 4):

Use `.each` function

```js
$('#MyId ul li a span').each(function(){
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyId">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Val1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Val2</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```